# How to reduce context menu size in Gnome?

Tags: gnome, dock, context-menu

As per shown in following image, after clicking on context menu of Gnome Dock following menu comes.

Can we reduce size between options? Those red mark area can we reduce?

[image: Gnome 3.20 Dash to Dock context menu]

Comment: It is unclear whether that is the "gnome dock" or if this is due to a theme.

Comment: I haven't applied any theme its default theme Adwaita only and used plugin is Dash to Dock.

Comment: Maybe not a gtk theme but a shell theme? Haven't used gnome shell really but that doesn't look like the screen captures of that plugin.

Comment: I had gnome and the spacing was just like that and the icons on the top bar are spaced like that too. The solution was to change the theme, Arc looked really good for me on gnome.

Comment: There might be way, we can do some css change(s) to minimize the gap between menus.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know whether/how this can be fixed for the default theme, however, if you're using a custom Shell theme, you can do the following:

Open the `gnome-shell.css` stylesheet of your theme (could be any Gtk theme that contains a GNOME shell theme):

```
sudo -H gedit /usr/share/themes/<your-theme>/gnome-shell/gnome-shell.css
```

Search for the `.popup-menu-ornament` element and change the `height` to reduce spacing.

The `popup-menu-ornament`'s are the yellow boxes in this screenshot:

[image]

This way I was able to reduce the spacing for the `Flat Plat compact` theme I'm using.

NOTE: There might be better ways to do this and this might even not work for all themes. Feedback is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

well , My solution wont differ too much from the previous solution of "@Tim Süberkrüb" you do the same first step:

```
  cd /usr/share/themes/<Shell-Theme-In-Use>/gnome-shell
```

then, the second step :

```
  sudo gedit gnome-shell.css
```

the third step:

- search for popup-menu-context and popup-menu-item
- set padding for both of them 1px, well, you could put any value even 0px, but I saw this good choice.

The final result 
[right-click popup-menu gnome desktop 3.36 ubuntu 20.04](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7lCo6.jpg)