# How can I resize the size of right-click tooltip menu on Ubuntu dock?

Tags: menu, ubuntu-dock, tooltip

I just don't like that size of the menu when I right-click on Ubuntu docked icons, please help me if you can.

[image: Screenshot of my case]

See attached screenshot for clarity.

Comment: Probably, you will need to edit .css files of your theme, see https://askubuntu.com/questions/873863/how-to-reduce-context-menu-size-in-gnome